# Error when trying run rails server on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

i got error when try to run "rails server", i am following intruction from this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwaeRJRoCeo

this is what I get:

```
C:\ruby\rails\firstapp>rails server
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:i
n `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::G
enerator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails_generator/ba
se.rb:90:in `<class:Base>'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails_generator/ba
se.rb:85:in `<module:Generator>'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails_generator/ba
se.rb:48:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails_generator/ba
se.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `
require'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `
require'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails_generator.rb
:34:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `
require'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `
require'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.1.0/bin/rails:13:in `<top
(required)>'
        from C:/ruby/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        from C:/ruby/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

i try to change 
In config/environments/development.rb:

```
firstapp::Application.configure do
```

still got error

Comment: Try to start server using `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: Still error Sravan, http://pastebin.com/RNcSZ32E

Answer (score 0):

Last time, i had a problem same as you. You can do this to fix it.

```
gem uninstall rmagick 
gem cleanup 
bundle install
```

It worked for me. You can try it.

Comment: will try Khanh Pham

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, in windows, i can run in port 3000
now i try use this:

```
rails server -p 80
```

its work